# Crystal Report Export to Excel (data Only) is missing Page header

Tags: crystal-reports

I have crystal report with 2 page headers (PHa and PHb) when i export this report to excel by selecting Excel (Data Only ) option the PHa is missing the exported excel.I tried to suppress the PHb to display PHa when it is exported to excel but by doing so the output excel has not heading displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing this from Crystal, try the following.

When you export to Excel (Data Only), under the Excel Format Options, choose Custom.

Expand the Options.

Ensure to **uncheck** *Simplify page headers*